# Adjusting proper anchoring in windows form when you have labels and text boxes combined

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this problem when i want to put a few labels and text boxes in a row in a Windows Form.
My idea is when I resize the window I want all text boxes to resize equally and to be proportional to the new window size. I tried to do this with Panels and basically this is an example of that
[image]

When i change the size of the window what i get is
[image]

So basically my text boxes expand equally till they reach one of the other two Panels and after that only the right text box expands. What I did is set anchor to left and right to all components.

Has anyone solved this problem, i would really appreciate the help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [TableLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx) with a single row and 3 (or 6) columns instead.